# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, range

Why AppScript in google sheets doesn't find the range in the sheet?The SpreadsheetApp finds the sheet but shows error in line 6.

I tried ActiveRange and just getRange defining this in the sheet, but I always see this error.

Please help me I'm not a programmer.

Below is my function:

```
function sendEmailtoworkers() { 
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = ss.getSheetByName('number')[0];
    let list = sheet.getRange(2,2,9,2);
    MailApp.sendEmail( list, "пупкин", "Пожалуйста, зайди на этот файл: docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/…);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Here is a code: function sendEmailtoworkers() {

let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let sheet = ss.getSheetByName('number') [0];

let list = sheet.getRange(2,2,9,2);



MailApp.sendEmail( list, "пупкин", "Пожалуйста, зайди на этот файл: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1om2RBSGA1P-b48VsggEAWzV2ZKQoHVaR/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115274424199304071490&rtpof=true&sd=true");

}

Comment: Thank you, but please [edit] that into your question as a formatted code block as I described in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

`getSheetByName('number')` will give you the sheet object, you're trying to access `[0]` from that, which returns `undefined`.

You can either use

```
let sheet = ss.getSheetByName('number')
```

or

```
let sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
```

`getSheets()` returns list of sheet objects, you can access through index.
To know more,  [click here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))!